# Error adding annotations to map view

Tags: swift, core-data, mapkit

I have an app in which I get data from a Core Data model, which then I wish to present on a map. When I add annotations to the map view I get the error: Could not cast value of type 'Swift._ContiguousArrayStorage<>' () to 'MKAnnotation' (). This same logic worked with Swift 2, but apparently not with Swift 3. Where and how do I add the notations to the map view. The code is:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    var rainFallGauges = [RainFallGauge]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "RainFallGauge")

    do {
        rainFallGauges = try coreDataStack.context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [RainFallGauge]

        obsCount = rainFallGauges.count
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    if obsCount == 0 {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "No gauges found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {

        for rainFallGauge in rainFallGauges {

            resultsGauge = rainFallGauge.value(forKey: "gaugeName") as? String
            resultsLatitude = rainFallGauge.value(forKey: "gaugeLatitude") as? String
            resultsLongitude = rainFallGauge.value(forKey: "gaugeLongitude") as? String
            print(resultsGauge)

            if (resultsLatitude != nil && resultsLongitude != nil)  && (resultsLatitude?.isEmpty == false && resultsLongitude?.isEmpty == false) {
                let latNSString = NSString(string: resultsLatitude!)
                setLatitude = latNSString.doubleValue
                print(setLatitude)

                let longNSString = NSString(string: resultsLongitude!)
                setLongitude = longNSString.doubleValue
                print(setLongitude)

                self.gauges.append(Gauges(gaugeTitle: resultsGauge, latitude: setLatitude, longitude: setLongitude))
                print(gauges.count)
            } else if gauges.count == 0 {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "No gauges", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    self.gaugeMap.delegate = self
    self.gaugeMap.addAnnotation(self.gauges as! MKAnnotation)

    gaugeMap.mapType = .hybrid

    let rectToDisplay = self.gauges.reduce(MKMapRectNull) {
        (mapRect: MKMapRect, gauge: Gauges) -> MKMapRect in
        let placePointRect = MKMapRect(origin: gauge.location.mapPoint, size: MKMapSize(width: 0, height: 0))

        return MKMapRectUnion(mapRect, placePointRect)
    }
```

I have the array "gauges" declared above as:

```
    var gauges = [Gauges]()
```

and have created the Class Gauges to hold the relevant information for the annotations.

Any suggestions that will guide me to the correct syntax for the addAnnotation statement and where it should go would be appreciated.

Comment: This line makes no sense: `self.gaugeMap.addAnnotation(self.gauges as! MKAnnotation)` If `self.gauges` is a `[Gauges]` how can it possibly be an MKAnnotation? Don't tell me that worked somehow in Swift 2; it's nonsense no matter what language you're talking.

Comment: is Gauges subclass of MKAnnotation?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable insights, I misread the line in my old app it was actually:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your insights. I had misread the line in my old app, it was actually:

```
self.speciesMap.addAnnotations(self.places)
```

I solved my problem by simplifying and going to:

```
for rainFallGauge in rainFallGauges {

            resultsGauge = rainFallGauge.value(forKey: "gaugeName") as? String
            resultsLatitude = rainFallGauge.value(forKey: "gaugeLatitude") as? String
            resultsLongitude = rainFallGauge.value(forKey: "gaugeLongitude") as? String
            print(resultsGauge)

            if (resultsLatitude != nil && resultsLongitude != nil)  && (resultsLatitude?.isEmpty == false && resultsLongitude?.isEmpty == false) {
                let latNSString = NSString(string: resultsLatitude!)
                setLatitude = latNSString.doubleValue
                print(setLatitude)

                let longNSString = NSString(string: resultsLongitude!)
                setLongitude = longNSString.doubleValue
                print(setLongitude)

                gaugeMap.addAnnotation(OneGauge(title: resultsGauge, subtitle: "", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: setLatitude, longitude: setLongitude)))

            }
        }
    }
    gaugeMap.mapType = .hybrid
```